# API to access Cloudlyn

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am looking for any API or any way to access Microsoft's Cloudyn service. I want to extract data - Azure Storage Cost and utilization per month, this is available under the "Management Dashboard of Cloudyn" and want to integrate with Datadog.

1. Is there any way to access Cloudyn's data using PowerShell?
2. Is there any way Cloudyn API, that I can use to integrate with Datadog dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get access to data in Cloudyn is to configure a report and schedule data to be pushed to a storage account. From there, you can use standard storage account APIs to access the data.

Instead of using Cloudyn APIs, however, I would recommend using the [Cost Management Query API](https://aka.ms/costanalysis/api) for aggregated cost/usage data or [UsageDetails API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails) for raw usage.